# Minimum width of Expanded in a Wrap in Flutter for web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I searched for answer up and down, and finally I have to ask question here because I need a solution for 2 problems at once. I am quite new to Flutter.
I don't include code here because everything I tried did not work, and I believe they are wrong anyway, but basically I have let say 2 widgets on a row. The first one has a flexible width, and second one has fixed width. What I want is the first one has a minimum width so that when user resize the browser's width, if it goes below this minimum width the first widget, it will stop shrinking, and the second widget should go to (wrap around) next line/row. When user expand the browser width, and there are enough space for the minimum width of first widget and second widget, the second widget will get back on the same row of the first widget. And if we have even more extra space, then the extra space will go to the first widget (because it has flexible width)

Any idea?

Add pictures

[image: Normal size]
[image: Shrinking size]

```dart
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> 
> void main() => runApp(MyApp());
> 
> class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   // This widget is the root  
> // of your application.   @override   Widget build(BuildContext
> context) {
>     return MaterialApp(
>         title: "ListView.builder",
>         theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
>         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
>         home: ListViewBuilder());   } }
> 
> class ListViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {   @override   Widget
> build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("ListView.builder")),
>       body:
>           Wrap(
>             spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
>             runSpacing: 4.0,
>             children: <Widget>[
>               TextField(), 
>               ElevatedButton.icon(
>                 icon:const Icon(Icons.play_circle),
>                 label:const Text("Play record"),
>                 onPressed: null),
>               ElevatedButton.icon(
>                 icon:const Icon(Icons.stop_circle),
>                 label:const Text("Stop record"),
>                 onPressed: null),
>               ElevatedButton.icon(
>                 icon:const Icon(Icons.pause_circle),
>                 label:const Text("Pause record"),
>                 onPressed: null),
>             ],
>           )
>     );   } }
```

Comment: There is a widget called Wrap to do just this. You can have more info about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M&list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG&index=4

Comment: I already mention Wrap in my post title. It does not work. The first widget in an Expanded will take entire row all the time

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create conditions to change the layout and/or change the width. You can do this by writing a code like:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600 ? 
//your code if true 
: 
//your code if false.
```

You can also use the same thing for deciding the width of a container

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600 ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9 
// this will make the container width 90% of the screen width if the screen width was bigger than 600
:
300 
//This is will set the width to 300 (fixed  value) if the screen width was less than 600

)
```

Comment: This one I already tried too. The issue that I would like to know the width of the second widget, so I can do MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - Widget2.width. instead of MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9

Comment: Did you try using the MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * x to determine the size of the container wrapping the two widgets, then give widget1 a fixed price and use Expanded widget to widget2

Comment: Yes, it work well as the code intended. My issue is what do I put in x. I was simplify my question by state only 2 widgets, but actually there are like 3 fixed size widgets. Hence in Wrap, it will start to put these fixed size widget of to next line one by one because the flexible size widget hit the min width and refuse to shrink any more. Maybe I made the problem too complicated, perhaps I just put all 3 fixed size widget to next line (row)

Comment: Please share your code and/or images of what you're trying to do.